# After jquery ajax redirect success or cancel callbacks are not called

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect, cross-domain, single-sign-on

The following ajax call works fine for me:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/" + destination,
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    data:collectedData,
    success: successFunction,
    error:errorFunction
});
```

However as soon as redirects are followed the success or error handlers are not called. I also noticed that the X-Request-With: XmlHttpRequestHeader is missing in the redirects. The redirects are cross domain except the last one, which will redirect to the same origin. For Example:

```
request to     |   response
sameDomain     |   302 redirect to sso server (diffrent domain)
sso server     |   302 redirect to sso server
sso server     |   302 redirect to sameDomain
sameDomain     |   200 including valid json data
```

I am using Firefox 16

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JSOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

```
$.ajax({
     url:"/" + destination,
     dataType: 'jsonp', // Notice! JSONP <-- P (lowercase)
     data:collectedData,
     success:function(json){
         // do stuff with json (in this case an array)
         alert("Success");
     },
     error:function(){
         alert("Error");
     },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, do you think it is a cross domain issue?

Comment: yes. changed the code and see. let me know if there are any issues

Comment: I tried jsonp it works without redirects. but with redirect neither the success handler nor the error handler is called. the response is correct : jQuery11243({"testData":false})

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code like this

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/" + destination,
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    data:collectedData,
    success: function(data){},
    error:function(data){}
});
```